# angular2-highcharts first point loses on xAxis

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have the following options:

```
this.options = {
      title: { text: 'simple chart' },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 12) // feb 12, 2015
      }],
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          minute: '%H:%M',
          hour: '%H:%M',
          day: '%e. %b',
          week: '%e. %b',
          month: '%b \'%y',
          year: '%Y'
        }
      }
    };
```

When I choose datetime and click on button:

```
buttonClicked() {
    let pointStart=new Date(this.dateStart);
    let year=pointStart.getFullYear();
    let month=pointStart.getMonth()+1;
    let day=pointStart.getDate();
    let hours=pointStart.getHours();
    let minutes=pointStart.getMinutes();

    this.chart.series[0].update({
      data: [30, 41, 47, 52],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes, 0),
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }, true);
    // this.chart.redraw()
  }
```

After redraw() first point on xAxis is lost and chart looks like this:
[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: So there are only 3 values on the chart redraw as opposed to the 4 values in the chart you're showing, or are you referring to the label?

Comment: on mouseover information is shown for first point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data point numbered '30' is actually after the `13. Sep` Label, and so that label is removed since there are no points on or before it anymore. To control the which labels show up you will need to use a either xAxis.startOnTick or xAxis.minPadding (or a combination of both. Another option would be to use the Axis method setExtremes().

Documentation on [xAxis.startOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick), [xAxis.minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minPadding), and [Axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes).

Answer (score 1):

The first xAxis label indicates specific day at midnight (e.g Mar 12, 00:00), and your point is one hour further, so label disappears on update. Setting `minPadding` property with the higher value (e.g. 0.015) should help.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minPadding

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/shqpqq3b/

Comment: Thank you, it works nice. I accepted Z. Bagley's answer just because he answered 25 minutes earlier and he mentioned minPadding like you.